# Remove WooCommerce Marketing Menu Item (wp-admin) Using Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

With the new WooCommerce 4.1.0 just released, there's a new Marketing item in the menu. Looking at the URL, it goes to `admin.php?page=wc-admin&path=/marketing` and by using the `admin_menu` hook, I'm trying to remove this menu option.

I tried with the `sub_menu` option and with `remove_menu_page` option without success. If anyone can correct my code I would be very grateful.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_woocommerce_marketing_menu_option' );
function remove_woocommerce_marketing_menu_option(){
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=wc-admin&path=/marketing' );
}
```

Comment: Disable the WooCommerce marketing hub menu item from wp-admin on child sites running version 4.1 of WooCommerce. https://meta.mainwp.com/t/disable-marketing-hub-menu-item-from-woocommerce-4-1/989

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r - that worked. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

**For WooCommerce <= v4.2**

```
// Remove Marketing Hub menu item
add_filter( 'woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', '__return_empty_array' );
```

**For WooCommerce >= v4.3**

WooCommerce 4.3 removed the `woocommerce_marketing_menu_items` filter so the above snippet will no longer work. Thankfully, we can hook into another filter introduced in WooCommerce 4.0 as such:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_features', function( $features ) {
    /**
     * Filter list of features and remove those not needed     *
     */
    return array_values(
        array_filter( $features, function($feature) {
            return $feature !== 'marketing';
        } ) 
    );
} );
```

**Is the code working?**

I have tested the above code snippet on WordPress version 5.5 and WooCommerce version 4.4 and it works as expected.

**Coupons moved under Marketing in WooCommerce 4.4**

In WooCommerce version 4.4, the Coupons feature was moved to the Marketing menu item as sub-item. There will still be a coupon menu item in the old location, and anyone stumbling upon it will be guided on the new location and asked to remove the legacy `WooCommerce > Coupons` menu item.

However, if you are using the above code snippet, your `Marketing`, and so, the `Marketing > Coupons` menu items will be not available. In that case, your `Coupons` menu item will reside in the old place as `WooCommerce > Coupons`.

Credits: https://cinchws.com/remove-woocommerce-marketing-hub-menu-item/

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', 'woocommerce_marketing_menu_items');

function woocommerce_marketing_menu_items($marketing_pages){
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this For WooCommerce Version <= 4.2 :

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_marketing_menu_page' );

function remove_marketing_menu_page() {
    remove_menu_page( 'wc-admin&path=/marketing' );
}
```

For WooCommerce Version >= 4.3
Use this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_features', function( $features ) {
    return array_values(
        array_filter( $features, function($feature) {
            return $feature !== 'marketing';
        } ) 
    );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove Marketing Hub menu item
add_filter( 'woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', '__return_empty_array' );
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.