# Disabling WooCommerce Marketing without disabling Shipping functions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This solution (or most others) disable the Marketing, but also the Shipping functions in WooCommerce, specifically the popup settings and toggle for the three default shipping options (Local Pickup, Free, and Flat Rate)

The following solution is from [Remove WooCommerce Marketing Menu Item (wp-admin) Using Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635815/remove-woocommerce-marketing-menu-item-wp-admin-using-hook) - and this is (one of the solutions) that disables the shipping as well as marketing

> **For WooCommerce >= v4.3**
>
> WooCommerce 4.3 removed the `woocommerce_marketing_menu_items` filter so the above snippet will no longer work. Thankfully, we can hook into another filter introduced in WooCommerce 4.0 as such:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_features', function( $features ) {
    /**
     * Filter list of features and remove those not needed     *
     */
    return array_values(
        array_filter( $features, function($feature) {
            return $feature !== 'marketing';
        } ) 
    );
} );
```

Here is the console error log:

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.4.2:5 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.4.1
wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ShippingCurrencyContext')
    at addCurrencySymbol (wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1:8821)
    at wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1:8505
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at n.reformatSettingsHTML (wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1:8491)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onConfigureShippingMethod (wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1:7102)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.4.2:2:40035)
    at v.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.4.2:2:38006)
addCurrencySymbol @ wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1
(anonymous) @ wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1
reformatSettingsHTML @ wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1
onConfigureShippingMethod @ wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.4.0:1
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.4.2:2
v.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.4.2:2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following revisited code version (for WooCommerce v4.3 and above):

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_features', 'disable_marketing_feature');
function disable_marketing_feature($features){
    $key = array_search('marketing', $features);
    if ( ! empty($key) ) {
        unset($features[$key]);
    }
    return $features;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

---

For WooCommerce prior versions *(< v4.3)*, simply use:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', '__return_empty_array');
```